# How to fix IONIC V1 build Gradle Process

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle

[To generate a release build for Android, I can use the following Cordova cli command:

$ ionic cordova build --release android][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDebX.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

Or

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: delete www folder on your project then try build commond

Comment: is that possible to build without WWW folder Praveen Kumar

Comment: use this one ionic cordova build android

after that open android studio sign apk and release.